# express-generator not getting installed

Tags: node.js, express

Referring to http://expressjs.com guide, I'm trying to install express-generator as follows.

`npm install express-generator -g`

I've also tried `npm install -g express-generator` but nothing worked out. Below is the error in all cases.

```
C:\Sandbox\exp>npm install -g express-generator
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "express-generator"
npm ERR! node v6.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Not Found: express-generator
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'express-generator' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)

npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Sandbox\exp\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: `npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Sandbox\exp\npm-debug.log` Could you post the contents of this file?

Comment: are you doing this on a VM and if yes are you sure your VM can connect to internet?

Comment: That seems like more of proxy error:
18 http request GET http://npm-registry.fm.xxxx.net/express-generator
19 http 404 http://npm-registry.fm.xxx.net/express-generator

Answer (score 0):

After couple of days of research, I've resolved the issue. (rather I should say, found a workaround that worked for me)

1 - Install Fiddler
2 - Go to menu Rules, select Automatic Authenticate
3 - Go to menu Customize Rule, this will open a text file.
4 - Search for below snippet

```
   if (m_AutoAuth) {
        oSession["X-AutoAuth"] = "(default)";
    }
```

5 - Replace with below

```
   if (m_AutoAuth) {
        oSession["X-AutoAuth"] = "DOMAIN\username:password";
    }
```

6 - Update npm proxy

```
npm config set proxy http:localhost:8888
```

That's it. You're done.

Only thing, you must keep running fiddler.

We have re-route all internet calls through Fiddler and fiddler is handling all proxy issues.

Hope this helps!!